# LaTeX Special Arrow Symbol

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know how to typeset the arrow in the photo below? It is in Algebra: Chapter 0 by Paolo Aluffi, but I cannot find it anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It looks like `A \stackrel{\sim}{\to} B` with the older arrows. Two identical options are below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\slippery}{\overset{\sim}{\to}}
\newcommand{\mapping}{\stackrel{\sim}{\to}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A &\slippery B\\
A &\mapping B
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

where `\overset` belongs to `amsmath`. In case of confusion, I choose what `amsmath` offers for purely psychological reasons.

[image]